# AppleScript - Creating a variable folder and then using rsync to copy to that location?

Tags: applescript

I would like to have an apple script that backups up a user to a smb drive.

So far I have managed to create the folder with variables in the correct location. This includes the date and the short username of the current user.

Im struggling now with using rsync to copy the user folder to the newly created variable folder on the smb.

```
-- Ask for computer type
set ComputerList to {"macbookair", "macbookpro", "imac", "macmini"}
set ComputerType to choose from list ComputerList with title "Users 
Machine" with prompt "What Type of Machine Does the User Have?" 
default items "macbookair"

-- Looks for Username
set userName to short user name of (system info)

-- Sets path where folder created
set p to alias "link:to:smb:volume:"

-- Sets current date
set d to short date string of (current date)
set FullDate to d

-- Creates the folder
tell application "Finder" to make new folder at p with properties 
{name:FullDate & "_" & userName & "-" & ComputerType}

-- Copies the data
do shell script "rsync -zaP ~/ 
/Volumes/Goes/Here/VARIABLEFOLDERHERE --exclude='Library' -- 
exclude='Public' --exclude='Applications"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the result of the line which creates the folder.

Shell scripts expect POSIX paths and it's highly recommended to escape paths always with `quoted form of`

```
tell application "Finder" 
    set newFolder to make new folder at p with properties {name:FullDate & "_" & userName & "-" & ComputerType}
    set newFolderPOSIX to POSIX path of (newFolder as text)
end tell

do shell script "rsync -zaP ~/" & space & quoted form of newFolderPOSIX & space & "--exclude='Library' --exclude='Public' --exclude='Applications'"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!